# Calculating Schubert Varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

This question is also asked in stackexchange.

Let $G$ be a reductive group, and $\mu\in X_{\bullet}(T)$ a coweight. Then the Schubert variety $Gr_{\leq\mu}$ is defined to be

$$Gr_{\leq\mu}:=\{(E,\beta)\in Gr_G|Inv(\beta)\leq\mu\},$$

where $Gr_G$ is the affine Grassmannian of $G$ and $Inv(\beta)\in G(\mathcal{O})\backslash G(F)/G(\mathcal{O})$ via the Cartan decomposition.

I am interested in the following special case. Let $G=GL_n$, for $\mu=(u_1,u_2,\cdots,u_n)$, how can we describe the Schubert variety $Gr_{\leq\mu}$ in terms of lattices?

Thank you in advance for any comments and answers! I also appreciate if you would like to provide some reference which helps to solve this problem.

Comment: One place these conditions are spelled out is Snider's thesis http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1011.3705 section 3.4.

Comment: @AllenKnutson Thank you so much Professor Knutson. I will take a look at the paper.